# in digit-interacting demo file, it doesn't load image file

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to execute digit demo file from your digit-interacting github(https://github.com/zc-alexfan/digit-interacting). I followed the direction and I executed the "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python demo.py --eval_on minival --load_from saved_models/db7cba8c1.pt  --num_workers 0" line but I've got an error message following next.

```
Loaded pretrained weights: saved_models/db7cba8c1.pt
>>> Defrost ALL
Creating val dataset...
Loading annotation from ./data/InterHand/rootnet_output/rootnet_interhand2.6m_output_val.json
Load annotation from  ./data/InterHand/annotations/val
Get bbox and root depth from ./data/InterHand/rootnet_output/rootnet_interhand2.6m_output_val.json
Reading pickle..
Reading pickle: Done
Fetched lmdb handle
Processing annotation ..
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 27136.18it/s]
Number of annotations in single hand sequences: 617
Number of annotations in interacting hand sequences: 383
Total number of annotations: 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 36, in <module>
    demo_model(cfg)
  File "demo.py", line 23, in demo_model
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(loader):
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 634, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 678, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/digit-interacting/src/dataset/image_dataset.py", line 258, in __getitem__
    ) = augmentation(
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/digit-interacting/src/utils/preprocessing.py", line 106, in augmentation
    img, trans, inv_trans = generate_patch_image(img, bbox, do_flip, scale, rot, input_img_shape, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/digit/digit-interacting/src/utils/preprocessing.py", line 176, in generate_patch_image
    img_height, img_width, img_channels = img.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

Here is my current state of package.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
absl-py                   2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
brotli-python             1.0.9            py38h6a678d5_7  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2023.12.12           h06a4308_0  
cachetools                4.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2024.2.2         py38h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
comet-ml                  3.38.1                   pypi_0    pypi
configobj                 5.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
cuda-cudart               11.8.89                       0    nvidia
cuda-cupti                11.8.87                       0    nvidia
cuda-libraries            11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc                11.8.89                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvtx                 11.8.86                       0    nvidia
cuda-runtime              11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
dulwich                   0.21.7                   pypi_0    pypi
everett                   3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ffmpeg                    4.3                  hf484d3e_0    pytorch
filelock                  3.13.1           py38h06a4308_0  
freetype                  2.12.1               h4a9f257_0  
future                    1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gmp                       6.2.1                h295c915_3  
gmpy2                     2.1.2            py38heeb90bb_0  
gnutls                    3.6.15               he1e5248_0  
google-auth               1.35.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.62.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4              py38h06a4308_0  
imageio                   2.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        7.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       6.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         hdb19cb5_46306  
jinja2                    3.1.3            py38h06a4308_0  
jpeg                      9e                   h5eee18b_1  
jsonschema                4.21.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1                pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
lame                      3.100                h7b6447c_0  
lcms2                     2.12                 h3be6417_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
lerc                      3.0                  h295c915_0  
libcublas                 11.11.3.6                     0    nvidia
libcufft                  10.9.0.58                     0    nvidia
libcufile                 1.8.1.2                       0    nvidia
libcurand                 10.3.4.107                    0    nvidia
libcusolver               11.4.1.48                     0    nvidia
libcusparse               11.7.5.86                     0    nvidia
libdeflate                1.17                 h5eee18b_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libiconv                  1.16                 h7f8727e_2  
libidn2                   2.3.4                h5eee18b_0  
libnpp                    11.8.0.86                     0    nvidia
libnvjpeg                 11.9.0.86                     0    nvidia
libpng                    1.6.39               h5eee18b_0  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libtasn1                  4.19.0               h5eee18b_0  
libtiff                   4.5.1                h6a678d5_0  
libunistring              0.9.10               h27cfd23_0  
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h5eee18b_0  
lmdb                      1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h6a678d5_0  
markdown                  3.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.3            py38h5eee18b_0  
matplotlib                3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2023.1.0         h213fc3f_46344  
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h5eee18b_1  
mkl_fft                   1.3.8            py38h5eee18b_0  
mkl_random                1.2.4            py38hdb19cb5_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.2                hb69a4c5_1  
mpmath                    1.3.0            py38h06a4308_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nettle                    3.7.3                hbbd107a_1  
networkx                  3.1              py38h06a4308_0  
numpy                     1.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.4.0.46                 pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.1.1                h4ff587b_0  
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h3ad879b_0  
openssl                   3.0.13               h7f8727e_0  
packaging                 23.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    10.2.0           py38h5eee18b_0  
pip                       23.3.1           py38h06a4308_0  
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pygit2                    1.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h06a4308_0  
python                    3.8.18               h955ad1f_0  
python-box                6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   2.0.0           py3.8_cuda11.8_cudnn8.7.0_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h7e8668a_5    pytorch
pytorch-lightning         0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pywavelets                1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
referencing               0.33.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.31.0           py38h06a4308_1  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
requests-toolbelt         1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rich                      13.7.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rpds-py                   0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
semantic-version          2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sentry-sdk                1.40.6                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.2.2           py38h06a4308_0  
simplejson                3.19.2                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
sympy                     1.12             py38h06a4308_0  
tbb                       2021.8.0             hdb19cb5_0  
tensorboard               2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2023.7.10                pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
torchaudio                2.0.0                py38_cu118    pytorch
torchtriton               2.0.0                      py38    pytorch
torchvision               0.15.0               py38_cu118    pytorch
tqdm                      4.66.2                   pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.9.0            py38h06a4308_1  
urllib3                   2.1.0            py38h06a4308_1  
websocket-client          1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.41.2           py38h06a4308_0  
wrapt                     1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wurlitzer                 3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.4.5                h5eee18b_0  
zipp                      3.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0  
zstd                      1.5.5                hc292b87_0
```

I've tracked the error, it seems to be happening in elytra.sys_utils.read_lmdb_image function. The content of 'fname' parameter is right but after "image_bin = txn.get(fname.encode('ascii'))" line, image_bin's type is NoneType. How can I solve this?